# Maintaining UI Responsiveness in C# or C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

This is somewhat of a general question, as I've been reading the MSDN C# tutorials/walkthroughs.  I've also looked through some posts here but wanted a more general answer.

I have just read the Asynchronous Programming section, and it seems like using async, await, and tasks is one of the suggested ways to run stuff while maintaining UI responsiveness.

I'm writing a C# program to control a robot to do certain tasks.  For example, the program will have a main UI that the user sets up, then when they hit "RUN" it will go through a sequence of tasks and then complete.  If I don't use any asynchronous or parallel programming, the UI will hang until completion.

My question is, what is the typical way of handling these situations?  Based on what I've read I can do the following in C#:

1. Make the "RUN" button click handler async so I can await tasks
2. Run each of my synchronous operations as a task and await for them to complete in the "RUN" handler - for example:

   `Task t = synchronousMethod1();
    await t;
    t = synchronousMethod2();
    await t;
    repeat...`

Is this the best way to do it?  If you imagine I have a lot of robot motions to do, I would have to create a lot of tasks to execute each motion while maintaining UI responsiveness.  Each task would have minimal computing requirements and would complete fairly quickly however but I'm not sure if this is good practice or not.

Also, out of curiosity, what is the standard way of doing this in C++?

Comment: well you also should take a look at [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case it's seems that your tasks/actions have to run one after each other so it's better to use background worker as it also report progress very easily

Comment: @Franck async/await also allows progress reporting. BackgroundWorker is basically deprecated, and should generally not be used if async/await can be used instead. The latter has many advantages, including being easier to test

Comment: @leonhart88 I'm not sure you'd gain anything by using multiple tasks, and you might get into sticky situations that would be hard to debug. Assuming each motion relies on the previous one being completed, then one task is the way to go. Your UI would be responsive, and you'd be guaranteed that your motions would run in the right order

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Yes I also read that BackgroundWorker is deprecated.  Good point about not needing multiple tasks.

I may need to break the tasks up, or have nested tasks (is this bad?) though.  For example, I may tell to the robot to go to position 1, image, position 2, image, position 3, image.  After each image I would want to do some processing.  I could do this all sequentially in one task, but if I can go to position 1, image & create a task, go to position 2, image & create a task, etc., and then await all those tasks, I feel that might be more efficient.

Comment: What would be the best way to do the above?  Have one main run task that the UI button handler awaits on, which is an async method which generates a list of tasks during the imaging and awaits for those?